# Automatic Excel Saving in .xlk format

Tags: excel

When I save my files which extensions are .xls and .xlsm,
it automatically saves to the desktop by creating a copy in .xlk format.

How can I turn this off? If anyone can help, I would be glad.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the workbook press `F12` (Save As), then click on `Tools` (next to `Save` button) then on `General Options`, and uncheck the 'Always Create Backup` checkbox